# Spring Hibernate "could not resolve property" on custom @Query with inner join on @ManyToMany @JoinTable

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hql

I have a class like this:

```
@Entity(name = "LP_TEMPLATE")
public class LpTemplate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "TEMPLATE_APPS",
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "appId") },
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "templateId") })
    private Set<LpApp> apps = new HashSet<>();

    ...

}
```

and I try to write a method in a repository to get all LpTemplate instances for a given appId. It is basically the reverse of this @ManyToMany mapping.

```
@Repository
public interface LpTemplateRepository extends JpaRepository<LpTemplate, Long> {

    @Query("select T from LP_TEMPLATE as T inner join T.apps as TA on T.id = TA.templateId AND TA.appId = ?1")
    List<LpTemplate> findTemplatesWithApp(long appId);

}
```

However, I get an exception at startup saying: **could not resolve property: templateId of: test.LpApp**

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: could not resolve property: templateId of: test.LpApp [select T from test.LpTemplate as T inner join T.apps as TA on T.id = TA.templateId AND TA.appId = ?1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:611) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

My previous version (which also didn't work btw) was like this:

```
@Repository
public interface LpTemplateRepository extends JpaRepository<LpTemplate, Long> {

    @Query("select T from LP_TEMPLATE as T inner join TEMPLATE_APPS as TA on T.id = TA.templateId AND TA.appId = ?1")
    List<LpTemplate> findTemplatesWithApp(long appId);

}
```

And the exception I got here was: **Path expected for join!**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [select T from test.LpTemplate as T inner join TEMPLATE_APPS as TA on T.id = TA.templateId AND TA.appId = ?1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:611) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your LpApp class.

Comment: @ScanQr LpApp has nothing interesting. An ID declared just like it is in LpTemplate and some other String properties, getters and setters. There is no back reference to the LpTemplate class.

Answer (score 0):

You get error ,

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: could
>   not resolve property: templateId of: test.LpApp

This indicates that you are referring to a column (property) in `LpApp` class with `templateId` which does not exists in it. Make sure you define or mark a property in `LpApp` as `templateId`.

Comment: Do I really need that property in LpApp? I would prefer to keep the LpApp class "clean", that is without implementation details, if possible. If you say that a property in LpApp is necessary though I will have no other choice but to add that property.